# Flutter Future<HttpClient> is not a substype of HttpClinet

Tags: flutter, ssl-certificate, dio

```dart
import 'dart:io';    
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_retrofit/example.dart';

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: this._getPosts(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.none:
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
                break;
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
                break;
              case ConnectionState.active:
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
                break;
              case ConnectionState.done:
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
                break;

              default:
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future _getPosts() async {
    final dio= Dio();
    (dio.httpClientAdapter as DefaultHttpClientAdapter).onHttpClientCreate = await (client) async {
      SecurityContext securityContext=new SecurityContext();
      final ByteData crtData = await rootBundle.load('assets/server.crt');
      securityContext.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(crtData.buffer.asUint8List());
      final ByteData keyBytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/server.key');
      securityContext.usePrivateKeyBytes(keyBytes.buffer.asUint8List());
      return HttpClient(context: securityContext);
    };
    final client = RestClient(dio);
    client.login('mad***h@****.in', '88888');

  }
}
```

In flutter we are getting using Dio. I am getting a error using Dio The problem is here that i need to use SSl certificate So i used Dio But now i am getting the below error. Unhandled exception Future is not a subtype of HttpClient.

Comment: post the code where you  use `Future<Builder>`, also post the stacktrace you are getting

Comment: please find here above full code @pskink just edit the full code.

Comment: I don't see that you return something from `_getPosts` method

Comment: giving me same issue as well any luck with that?

Answer (score 3):

**Here is the solution**

**Create Http Client before dio code :**

```
SecurityContext clientContext = SecurityContext(withTrustedRoots: false);
var certificate =
    (await rootBundle.load("yourAssetCertificatePath"))
        .buffer
        .asInt8List();
clientContext.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(certificate);
HttpClient clientT = HttpClient(context: clientContext);
```

**Then call your dioAdapterCode :**

```
 final dio= Dio();
(dio.httpClientAdapter as DefaultHttpClientAdapter).onHttpClientCreate = (client) {
  return clientT ;
};
final client = RestClient(dio);
```

**Finaly your method would be :**

```
 Future _getPosts() async {
final dio= Dio();
 SecurityContext clientContext = SecurityContext(withTrustedRoots: false);
    var certificate =
        (await rootBundle.load("yourAssetCertificatePath"))
            .buffer
            .asInt8List();
    clientContext.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(certificate);
    HttpClient clientT = HttpClient(context: clientContext);
    (dio.httpClientAdapter as DefaultHttpClientAdapter).onHttpClientCreate =  (client)  {

  return clientT;
};
final client = RestClient(dio);
client.login('mad***h@****.in', '88888');
  }
```

**Note:**  Issue was use of async/await in the code.

Let me know if the issue persists and support the answer